# How can I define a boolean function argument to be optional?

Tags: actionscript-3

In ActionScript 3, is there a clean way to define a function that accepts an optional boolean argument ? As you may know, this is invalid :

```
public function test(param:Boolean = null):void {
    trace(param);
}
```

This triggers the following error: *VerifyError: Error #1102: Illegal default value for type Boolean*. Since, `Boolean` is a primitive, I guess it makes sense that it cannot be set to `null`. The only workaround I found is to cast the parameter to an object :

```
public function test(param:Object = null):void {
    trace(Boolean(param));
}
```

However, this does not feel very clean, particularly if you are developing libraries. ASDoc will generate API documentation that says the expected parameter is an `Object` whereas what is really needed is a `Boolean`.

Is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the good suggestions and discussion above I think that, in a library scenario and for simplicity's sake, the best way remains to type the parameter as `Object` with a default value of `null` but to request a `Boolean` in the API documentation :

```
/**
 * @param param Boolean object or null
 */
public function test(param:Object = null):void {
    trace(Boolean(param));
}
```

This allow the user of the library to pass a either a Boolean or nothing at all. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As you said Boolean can not be set to `null` value.

Therefore, you should specify a default value that is either `true` or `false`.

```
public function test(param:Boolean = false):void {
    trace(param);
}
```

But because you need the third case where nothing is set, one option could be to accept any Object but throw an exception if it is not null and not a boolean:

```
    public function test(param:* = null):void
    {
        if (param != null)
        {
            if ((param == true) || (param == false))
            {
                trace(Boolean(param).toString());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CustomError("param should be a boolean");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

Note that this solution also accept objects or primitives that can be compared to `true` or `false` such as `0`, `1`, or `[]`.

Comment: As I'm sure you understand, if I didn't need the third case, there would be no issue at all!

Comment: Boolean in AS3 can never be undefined. Even a 'var a:Boolean' is 'false' and not 'null'.

Comment: @Djip I think you have an issue with the design of your library then. Anyway I updated my answer after reading Marty's one and your comments.

Comment: @duTr This is sort of what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Djip I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should consider posting your own answer or accepting mine.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `optional`, I assume that you mean if there isn't a value supplied then something different should happen compared to if you had a `default` value of true or false.

You could make your own object to handle the three states that you need and maintain code readability by using a class like this:

```
public class Condition
{

    private var _value:* = null;


    public function Condition(initial:* = null)
    {
        value = initial;
    }


    public function set value(n:*):void
    {
        if(_value === null || _value === false || _value === true)
        {
            _value = n;
        }
    }


    public function get value():*{ return _value; }

}
```

And then your function could be:

```
function test(param:Condition = null):void
{
    if(param && param.value != null)
    {
        trace(param.value);
    }
}


test( new Condition() );
test( new Condition(true) );
```

Comment: I see your point and your solution would work. However, for a developer implementing my library, it would be weird to specify this new object instead of a good ol' boolean value.

Comment: I guess what I'm really hoping for is for primitives to behave like objects... In reality what I need is one of two states OR no state at all. I know I'm playing on words but if you could assign null to a primitive this is sort of what it would mean. Am I making any sense ?

Comment: @Djip Yeah I understand exactly what you mean, but unfortunately the primitive `boolean` does not accept any values other than `true` or `false`.

Comment: your logic is flawed. If 3 states are needed then Boolean is not what you need to be using to set the state. Personally I always liked the String approach with values of -1,0, and anything else.

Comment: @The_asMan I do not think my logic is flawed but I guess it's a matter of semantics. I only need 2 states: true or false. But if the value has not been set I want to take that into account.

Hypothetical example : I have a form with 3 true/false questions. I pass the 3 answers to a function (in the form of 3 boolean parameters). The functions adds 1 point for true answers, substracts 1 for false answers and does nothing for unanswered questions. It seems cleaner to me to pass booleans to the function instead of some 3-state special object.

Comment: @Marty Yeah, I guess I just have to live with it. I was hoping for some silver bullet that does not exist. I guess I'll stick to defining the parameter as an Object instead of a Boolean. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Djip Your logic as you just described clearly states that you want 3 states. You can not implement 3 state logic with a 2 state parameter. So yes boolean is not the parameter that you need for your logic. What you need is to use an int and test for 3 things. equal to 0 or null, anything less than 0, anything more than 0

Comment: @The_asMan I totally understand what you are saying. The question is, in the context of a library, what is the best way to setup this function so it is easy to understand and use. From the answers and my own original proposition, there are 3 possible approaches: a) type the parameters as * or Object and ask the user to supply either a Bool or nothing at all, b) create a 3-way object and type the parameter as such or c) type it as an int and use class constants to identify what can be interpreted as 3 states. Approach A and C are my favorite but A seems easier from the implementors perspective.

Comment: @Djip actually I just realized you stated a few comments ago that you are doing this due to 3 true/false questions. Then yes your logic is wrong. You should be using bitdata. IE: 1,2,4 as the values of the check boxes. or 001,010,100 and use bitmath to calculate the value

Comment: @The_asMan This was just a simplified example. It actually is not my use-case scenario at all. Using binary arithmetic does not change the problem which is to know what is the best way to implement this in a library scenario. In any case, if you absolutely want me to be wrong, then, I must be wrong...

Comment: @Djip It's not that you are wrong. It's just flawed logic. If you are making a library then there should be multiple attributes to set and in the setters of those attributes you would then handle the logic. When you introduce dynamic parameters like The accepted answer uses is a very bad practice for example what is to keep someone from passing in a movieClip not to mention since this is a library there is no way for the code hinting to determine that the proper parameter is a boolean.

Comment: @The_asMan If somebody passes in a MovieClip (assuming they are using a function without even reading the doc), it will be typecast as a Boolean and will be interepreted as TRUE. This does not feel like much of an issue to me. I can even think of scenarios where it might be deisrable. Dynamic parameters are used by many popular AS3 libraries for various reasons (TweenLite, Feathers, etc.). (cont)

Comment: @The_asMan For example, I wrote a library (SoftKeyboard) where the developer can pass either a single object to the constructor or a vector of the same objects. You might think of this as bad practice whereas I think of it as convenience. This is what is great with higher level languages. You do bring a good point though : perhaps that tricky parameter shouldn't be in the constructor at all. It could be set with a setter. If the setter simply isn't used, then I have my third case. This is becoming quite a discussion... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There was a tonne of discussion on my previous answer, but this **is the correct way** to have a function that accepts one of three states. My previous answer attempted to retain the use of a Boolean value like you were requesting, but that is not the right way to go about it.

Create a class that defines three values:

```
class State
{
    public static const EMPTY:int = -1;
    public static const FALSE:int = 0;
    public static const TRUE:int = 1;
}
```

Your function will accept an `int` (the type of each of the three properties within your `State` class). It will deal with the three possible values. You can use concise commenting to notify the developer of what thee values the function is expecting, referencing the `State` class. The default value can be `-1` aka `State.EMPTY`.

```
/**
 * Function description.
 * @param state One of three states, defined by State.
 */
function test(state:int = -1):void
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case State.EMPTY:
            // No value given.
        break;

        case State.TRUE:
            // True.
            //

        break;

        case State.FALSE:
            // False.
            //

        break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentError("Unsupported value for test()");
        break;
    }
}
```